# Regex validator not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex

***Updated***
I need to validate numbers, with decimal separator as , (comma) but this is not working:

```
validate.ValidationExpression = @"^[1-9]\d*(,\d+)?$";
```

123,01; 0,01; 0,001; 123456789,01 these are the numbers I would like to allow

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: provide some sample inputs as well. In what language?

Comment: @user3218114 sorry I updated because I need also numbers starting with 0 on this one. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the work

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*,?[0-9]+$
```

It validates all of your examples and it supports negative numbers and numbers without any floating part.

Comment: That would also capture `+,0` and `,123` since the first digit class has the asterisk multiplier on it.
Also, the decimal sign doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks, I unescaped the decimal sign.
As for `+,0` and `,123` they are valid in some languages.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^\d+(,\d+)?$
```

Visual explanation: 
http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%2B(%2C%5Cd%2B)%3F%24
That will:

- **^** Start at the beginning of a line
- **\d+** Find at least one, but as many as possible digits
- **(** Start of a group
- **,** The decimal sign
- **\d+** Find at least one, but as many as possible digits
- **)** End of the group
- **?** Makes the entire group optional
- **$** End of the line

This should capture integers and decimal numbers alike.
Try it out here:
http://regexr.com/398q6

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your numbers to be accepted (`123,01; 0,01; 0,001; 123456789,01`) you have to change the first number 1 to 0, like this:

```
validate.ValidationExpression = @"^[0-9]\d*(,\d+)?$";
```

since you are basicly saying that any number `1-9` followed by `,` and `0-9` are fine so it wont select the ones that has a `0` before the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

```
validate.ValidationExpression = @"^\d+[,]?\d*$";
```

this will accept both 90 and 90,000